# how to send millions of push notification from fcm in c#

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am able to send push notification to android and ios device using below code. Now i want to send more than 5 lack notification. I want to log response also into my db. So i have used threading but it is taking more than 12 hrs.

string applicationID = "dummyid";

```
            string senderId = "##########";

            string deviceId = regtoken;
            WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            var data = new
            {
                to = deviceId,
                notification = new
                {
                    body = message,
                    title = "",
                    sound = ""

                }
            };
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                        {
                            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                            String str = sResponseFromServer;
                        }
                    }
                }
                status = statusmessages();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string str = ex.Message;
            status = "failure";
        }


    return status;
```

Is their any way where i can send this notification faster.

Comment: Not only your code but the computer/server also needs to have enough processing power to do this job. You might want to use multiple servers and divide load among them so that they all work in parallel and do more work than single server.

Comment: you also want to run this code in multiple threads in parallel so that it can send to multiple senderid at the same time..

Comment: Yes... I am currently running 30+ threads for doing this job. But wanted some faster way to do it.

Comment: In firebase device group can i add 2-3 lacks of registration ids?? I read couple of articles and it have some limitations.

Comment: As I said.. its not only code.. the infra  also should be powerful enough... good code and makes things faster but not faster then what the server can handle...